# Using Twitter Bootstrap, how can I change the CSS style to respect line breaks?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap which sets the CSS styles for the `<pre>` tag so that line breaks are not preserved. What property do I need to change to reset the default behaviour?

```
<pre>
line 1
line 2
line 3
</pre>
```

produces

```
line 1 line 2 line 3
```

rather than

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Comment: hmm - i'm puzzled. it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sMMVG/

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your `display:block;` property is getting overridden. You need to set `pre{display:block;}` in your external stylesheets.
twitter bootstrap version 2 has  `pre` tag defined as `display:block;` by default, so it is obvious that you are overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a different element tag and going with a javascript code syntax highlighting API. The browser will not allow you to change how the pre tag works. You can't change the shadow DOM for a pre tag. If you are looking for more flexibility with your code snippets I would go this route.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_pre